# redirect page in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

In my `mainpage.xaml`, I check the localstorage, if the method GetAccept return false, I need to redirect to `Mentions.xaml` but the problem is that the NavigationService is Null in this step so i catch nullreferenceexecption

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            CacheManager cache = new CacheManager();
            if (!cache.GetAccept())
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/AppBar/Mentions.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
            InitializeComponent();
            }
```

How can I do this redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you put in a += = (sender, events)  You need to remove the extra = as I did below.

```
public MainPage() {

    InitializeComponent();
    CacheManager cache = new CacheManager();
    if (!cache.GetAccept())
    {            this.Loaded += (sender, event) =>{
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/AppBar/Mentions.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

very first follow this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx)

The `NavigationService` is instantiated when the current Page raises its Load event, in your solution your using an Un initialized `NavigationService` that's the cause for your `NullReference Exception`. So if you manually do the load event of the page then you'll get your NavigationService instance, following code is snippet for manually loading the page loaded event, write this right after your pages `InitializeComponent()` method

```
 this.Loaded += (sender, event) =>
  {
      var navigationService = NavigationService;
      navigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/AppBar/Mentions.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
  };
```

Comment: sender and event are not regognized by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the syntax correct.  Try copying what I put below.

```
this.Loaded += 
(
    (sender, event) =>
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/AppBar/Mentions.xaml",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    }
);
```

You are missing extra parenthesis and you have an extra semi-colon thrown in there.